# How to make a date string be read as a date object when saving excel files in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am currently using pandas in python to save my dataframes as csv files. I have a column 'date_arrived' that looks like ['01/03/2010','01/11/2010','01/01/2010','01/05/2010','01/08/2010'] where the dates are in dd/mm/yyyy format. When I save it to excel using df.to_csv(), the dates appear as a string object in excel and not a date object in excel. Is there anyway to change how to way excel reads the date in python?

Comment: `to_csv` writes as a comma separates values. for excel use `to_excel`

Comment: Try writing `df['date_arrived'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_arrived'], dayfirst=True)` the line of code before writing `.to_csv`.

Comment: @DavidErickson thank you! your solution works for the given format. I was wondering if my dates were in a different format ie 03 Jan 2020, is there any way to make excel preserve that format? your solution would turn it into 03/01/2020 date object in excel

Comment: @Beck, if you save it as an .xlsx file, you can specify whatever format you desire for the column.